# gmail: how to get notification for my gmail account to my server url?

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

Is it possible to get call my server API url every time if i receive email ?
I actually need to get the email whenever I receive new email through my API endpoint.

Comment: Try using [Gmail API Push Notification](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push), this will let you watch for changes to Gmail mailboxes. You can use this feature to improve the performance of your application. It allows you to eliminate the extra network and compute costs involved with polling resources to determine if they have changed. Whenever a mailbox changes, the Gmail API notifies your backend server application. Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with your solution but because of less experience I could not get success. I tried to follow, created project, topic, subscriber and added my server url in webhook but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a function of Gmail API. In this link you can see how to configure it with GCP pub/sub

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

Comment: I agree with your solution but because of less experience I could not get success. I tried to follow, created project, topic, subscriber and added my server url in webhook but it did not work.